# syslog-ng not writing to file

Tags: syslog-ng

I am new to syslog-ng, and want to test writing to a syslog from an external device.  The external device shows that it is "connected" to my syslog on port 516.  However, on my CentOS7 host nothing is being written to the log file (and now errors in /var/log/messages).  I tried telneting to localhost:516 and dumping in some text (as a test) but nothing is logged anywhere.  netstat confirms syslog is listening on tcp 516.

My config is below:

```
source s_test {
    system()
    internal()
    syslog(ip(0.0.0.0) port(516) transport("tcp"));
};
destination d_test { file("/var/log/test"); };
log { source(s_test); destination(d_test); };
```

Is there an error in my config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several errors are present. For one the `system()` and `internal()` need
to be terminated with `;`

```
source s_test {
    system();
    internal();
    syslog(ip(0.0.0.0) port(516) transport("tcp"));
};
destination d_test { file("/var/log/test"); };
log { source(s_test); destination(d_test); };
```

This yields new errors and warnings when `syslog-ng` is started manually
(the messages from `systemd` were useless for debugging on Centos 7):

```
# syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslogd.pid
WARNING: Configuration file has no version number, assuming syslog-ng 2.1 format. Please add @version: maj.min to the beginning of the file to indicate this explicitly;
...
Error parsing source, source plugin system not found in /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf at line 16, column 5:

system();
^^^^^^
```

These we can correct by including statements from the default
`syslog-ng` configuration file:

```
@version:3.5
@include "scl.conf"
source s_test {
    system();
    internal();
    syslog(ip(0.0.0.0) port(516) transport("tcp"));
};
destination d_test { file("/var/log/test"); };
log { source(s_test); destination(d_test); };
```

And now `syslog-ng` starts:

```
# syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslogd.pid
...
```

However, a `logger(1)` test fails from another terminal; the
`/var/log/test` log reports an `Invalid frame header` error:

```
# logger --server 127.0.0.1 --tcp --port 516 foo
```

This can be corrected by using `network` instead of `syslog`:

```
@version:3.5
@include "scl.conf"
source s_test {
    system();
    internal();
    network(ip(0.0.0.0) port(516) transport("tcp"));
};
destination d_test { file("/var/log/test"); };
log { source(s_test); destination(d_test); };
```

However I do not know whether you remote device needs `syslog` or
`network`.